# Allow ftp out through iptables

Tags: iptables, ftp

I have been having difficulty allowing ftp through iptables. Right now my ftp looks like this.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED multiport dports http,https,ftp,ftp-data
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination          

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I don't see anything wrong with it, but it doesn't work when I try to connect to it. (My ftp server is up, so that isn't an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me whether these `iptables` rules are on your client or your server. Your statement "*it doesn't work* when I try to connect to it" is not at all helpful. Please update your question to clarify these issues.

**If these rules are on your server** you can't conect to it from elsewhere because you haven't defined any rules that permit this.

**If this is on your client** then the reason it's failing it because you haven't allowed the inbound related data connection. Remember it's *from* tcp/21 on the server *to* a arbitrary high port on your client. Your `iptables` INPUT rule is expecting a related inbound session *to* tcp/21.

[These rules from devops-blog.net](http://www.devops-blog.net/iptables/iptables-settings-for-outgoing-ftp) should work for an outgoing client:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
```